# R- knitr:kable - How to display table without column names?

Tags: r, knitr, flexdashboard

Currently, I have this data frame (PS):

[image: Table with column header]

My code to display this table is:

```
kable(PS) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
```

I want to display the table without column names like this:
[image]

Problem is

1) The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results

2) If I convert the data frame and remove the column names and then use kable like this:

```
PS.mat <- as.matrix(PS)
colnames(PS.mat) <- NULL
kable(PS) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
```

I get the following error

```
Error in kable_info$colnames[[length(kable_info$colnames)]] : attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

I also tried the following parameter but with no results

```
kable(PS, col.names = NA)
```

EDIT 1:

A reproducible example:

```
if (!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
p_load("lubridate","knitr","kableExtra","scales")

Statistics <- c("AUM",
            "Minimum Managed Account Size",
            "Liquidity",
            "Average Margin / Equity",
            "Roundturns / $ Million / Year",
            "Incentive Fees",
            "Instruments Traded")
Value <- c("$30K","$30K","Daily","50%","6,933","25%","ES")
AI <- data.frame(Statistics,Value);
kable(AI) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik. added the example.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong edit. Updated again with a simple data frame.

Comment: Does your sample code work on your machine?  Because when I try to reproduce your error, it works fine after I figure out which libraries you are referring to (answer:  `knitr` and `kableExtra`, and the `%>%` pipe can be found in `magrittr` or `dplyr`)

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to add the libraries. My code uses all these libraries:
("xlsx","lubridate","gridExtra","ggplot2","knitr","kableExtra","scales","plyr","plotly") But for above mentioned code snippet knitr and kableExtra would be enough I guess.

Comment: @jan. thankyou for reading the question and suggesting an edit.
But here `library(pacman)` is not required because it already is done when `if(!require(pacman))` is run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on your desired output format you could make use of such functions. For pandoc:

```
x = kable(AI, format="pandoc") %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
cat(x[3:9], sep="\n")
```

For html:

```
x = kable(AI, format="html") %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
gsub("<thead>.*</thead>", "", x)
```

Comment: @urwaCFC: would you mind to mark the question as answered? thanks!

Comment: I thought I did. I had only upvoted. I have marked it as answered. Thanks once again.

Comment: Can you please answer this question:  It is a variant of above question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748726/r-knitrkable-removing-individual-headers-and-adding-single-header-on-multip

Thanks.