# How to remove/hide column names in kable?

Tags: r-markdown, kable

I am plotting a table using following code but I found there is unnecessary column names V1 and V2 appear as column name.

```
statdat<-read.table("stat.txt",sep="\t",header=FALSE)
kable(statdat)
```

[image]

How can I avoid printing the column name?

Comment: Have you tried the `col.names` argument?

Comment: Yes but col.names = null does not produce table

Answer (score 36):

You can set col.names to NULL to remove the column names:

```
kable(statdat, col.names = NULL)
```

An alternative solution is to use `format="pandoc"` and `cat()` to select the relevant rows after the table has been created. This solution is given here: [R- knitr:kable - How to display table without column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713731/r-knitrkable-how-to-display-table-without-column-names)